# Why is my Controller being bypassed sometimes?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have a spring web project, with a controller for editing customer details.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomerController {
    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/", ""}, method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public AjaxResponse updateCustomer(
        @RequestBody Customer customer
        ) {
// Update the customer in the service
    }
}
```

The javascript that does the ajax call

```
const customer = {/* get customer info from page */};
$.ajax({
    url: `${contextPath}/customers`
    , method: "POST"
    , accept: "application/json"
    , contentType: "application/json"
    , dataType: "json"
    , data: JSON.stringify(customer)
    , beforeSend: function() {
    }
    , complete: function() {
    }
    , success: function(ajaxResponse) {
        if (ajaxResponse.status !== "OK") {
            return;
        }
// update all references on the screen
    }
    , error: function(xhr, status, error) {
// log error
    }
});
```

Notice that the controller is using a `RequestMethod.PUT` and the ajax is using `, method: "POST"`
This gives me the error `POST http://localhost:8080/hub/customers 405 (Method Not Allowed)` and the Response Header contains `Allow: PUT`, which is completely fine. It tells me that the request is going to my controller.

If I change the ajax to `, method: "PUT"`, I get `PUT http://localhost:8080/hub/customers 404 (Not Found)`. When I check the response is `/hub/WEB-INF/views/customers.jsp The requested resource is not available.` notice the `/views/customers.jsp` This seems to be from the InternalResourceViewResolver.

From my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans:bean id="tilesViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="viewClass">
        <beans:value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
        </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="order">
        <beans:value>1</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix">
        <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="suffix">
        <beans:value>.jsp</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="order">
        <beans:value>#{tilesViewResolver.order+1}</beans:value>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

So it seems that when I the ajax method and the RequestMethod are not the same, it goes to the UrlBasedViewResolver, but when they are the same, it is bypassing that and going to the InternalResourceViewResolver. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ajax calls normally are suitable for handing responses like JSON, XML than views.
So, If you change your controller to `@RestContoller` from `@Controller`, this should work.